# What's the term for re-implementing an old API in terms of a newer API

Tags: terminology, api-design, backward-compatibility

The reason for doing it is to solve the case when a newer API is no longer backwards compatible with an older API.

To explain, just say that there is an old API v1.0. The maker of this API decides it is broken and works on a new API v1.1 that intentionally breaks compatibility with the old API v1.0. Now, any programs written against the old API cannot be recompiled as-is with the new API.

Then lets say there is a large app written against the old API and the developer doesn't have access to the source code. A solution would be to re-implement a "custom" old API v1.0 in terms of the new API v1.1 calls. So the "custom" v1.0 API is actually keeping the same interface/methods as the v1.0 API but inside its implementation it is actually making calls to the new API v1.1 methods.

So the large app can be then compiled and linked against the "custom" v1.0 API and the new v1.1 API without any major source code changes.

Is there a term for this practice?

*There's a recent example of this happening in [Jamie Zawinski's port of XScreenSaver to the iPhone](http://www.jwz.org/blog/2012/06/i-have-ported-xscreensaver-to-the-iphone/) - he re-implemented the OpenGL 1.3 API in terms of the OpenGL ES 1.1 API. In this case, OpenGL 1.3 represents the "old" API and OpenGL ES 1.1 represents the "new" API.*

Comment: API 1.0 would effectively become an [adapter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern) of API 1.1? If so, there's your answer...

Comment: You need a name for your patterns book.  How about Back to the Future Adapter?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understand you right, you'd be implementing the [adapter pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern) to isolate the API calls from the rest of your application. So when the time came to switch from v1.0 to v1.1, you'd just modify your API wrapper implementation to make different calls and the rest of your application wouldn't know or care.

So your application structure would look something like this:

```
.----------.       .-------------.       .----------.
| Your App | ----> | API Wrapper | ----> | API v1.0 |
'----------'       '-------------'       '----------'
                              |
                              |          .----------.
                              `--------> | API v1.1 |
                                         '----------'
```

Comment: Posting my comment as an answer? Well done! ;P

Comment: +1 To the comment and the answer. So this is where Anna gets all her extra rep from ;)

Comment: @YannisRizos The timestamps are *almost* on my side. :P

Comment: 29 seconds too late is still too late!

Comment: Thanks for the great answer and diagram! In the diagram I think you don't need the 'API wrapper' block though? - because the API v1.0 has effectively become the adaptor for API 1.1. I think you just need an arrow pointing down from API v1.0 to API v1.1?

Comment: @dodgy_coder This'd be the typical approach, but the principle is the same. Normally, you wouldn't be able to modify API v1.0's source, so you'd create a separate adapter. All that really matters, though, is that your code calls methods in a class you control and can update. This also sets you up for moving to v1.2, 1.5, 2.0, whatever. :)

Comment: The adapter part of the answer is good, but I think the diagram misses an important point.  The APIWrapper class has an interface identical to API v1.0.  (I'll admit I don't know the correct ASCII art UML construct for this, though).

Comment: @psr I went with a general diagram. Doesn't terribly matter what the interface is. It can be borrowed from API v1.0 or not.

Comment: @YannisRizos c'mon other guys repost her [comments](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136537/is-too-old-to-migrate-a-good-reason-not-to-migrate/136554#comment381664_136543) as an [answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/136554/165773), why can't Anna do the same? :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Anna Lear and Yannis Rizos for their answer, i.e. that the API 1.0 has effectively become an adaptor for API 1.1.

I just wanted to put forward a more specific answer. In my case the API 1.0 has retained the same public interface, so the application doesn't need to change. The only thing that has changed is the internal implementation of the API 1.0 itself - it now has a dependency on the new API 1.1. So instead of *"porting the application"* to use API 1.1, we're *"porting the API"*.

[image: Porting an API]